# Differing return values for os.execute when called directly from Lua or from LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, latexmk

Consider the following LuaTeX file.

```
#################################
foo.tex
#################################
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.lua}
  assert(os.execute([[ latexmk x.tex ]]) == 0)
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{x.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\directlua{foo = require "foo.lua"}
\end{document}
#################################
```

The assert fails if I run the Lua code.

```
lua5.3 foo.lua
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 25 October 2018, version: 4.61.
Latexmk: All targets (x.dvi) are up-to-date
lua5.3: foo.lua:7: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        foo.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

But if I run the LuaTeX code with "luatex" I still get the assert error:

```
lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.086 seconds
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./foo.lua'.

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./x.tex'.

(./foo.aux)./foo.lua:7: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        ./foo.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.19 \directlua{foo = require "foo.lua"}
```

However, if I use "luatex -shell-escape" I don't get the assert error.

```
lualatex -shell-escape foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.094 seconds
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./foo.lua'.

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./x.tex'.

(./foo.aux)Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 25 October 2018, version: 4.61.
Latexmk: All targets (x.dvi) are up-to-date
 (./foo.aux))
 384 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 44 glue_spec
, 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:7,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

I don't understand the reason for this behavior. If I replace the
`assert` line with

```
assert(os.execute([[ foobar ]]) == 0)
```

for example, I see the assert error either way.

EDIT: I figured out that the reason is that `os.execute` returns different values, depending on whether `-shell-escape` is passed to LuaTeX or not. This is probably documented somewhere, but was surprising to me.

So, what's the reason for that, and where is it documented, if anywhere? For the record, I obtained the values with

```
x, y, z = os.execute([[ latexmk x.tex ]])
print(string.format("execute return values are %s, %s, %s", x, y, z))
```

and they appear to be (without `-shell-escape`)

> execute return values are nil, Command execution disabled via shell_escape='p', nil

and with `-shell-escape`

> execute return values are 0, nil, nil

The values directly from Lua are

> execute return values are true, exit, 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lua backend adheres to `--shell-escape` the same way `\write18` does.  This is also documented in the manual.

> ## 4.2.4 Executing programs
>
> In keeping with the other TeX-like programs in TeX Live, the two Lua functions
>   `os.execute` and `io.popen`, as well as the two new functions `os.exec` and
>   `os.spawn` that are explained below, take the value of `shell_escape` and/or
>   `shell_escape_commands` in account. Whenever LuaTeX is run with the assumed
>   intention to typeset a document (and by that we mean that it is called as
>   `luatex`, as opposed to `texlua`, and that the command line option `--luaonly`
>   was not given), it will only run the four functions above if the matching
>   `texmf.cnf` variable(s) or their `texconfig` (see section 10.4) counterparts
>   allow execution of the requested system command. In “script interpreter” runs
>   of LuaTeX, these settings have no effect, and all four functions have their
>   original meaning.

In fact, LuaTeX's `os.execute` (and `io.popen`) is fundamentally different from plain Lua's variants.  You can compare the source for `os_execute` in [LuaTeX](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/b6256e1c692f16a1758dffa6a28c354d3214beb0/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/loslibext.c#L988-L1035) with the one from [plain Lua](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/loslib.c.html#os_execute)

Comment: Well, ok. But why are the return values for `os.execute` different, depending on whether the code is called from Lua directly, or from LuaTeX?

Comment: @FaheemMitha LuaTeX has its own implementation for `os.execute` and `io.popen` to take the shell escape stuff into account.  Why the return values were chosen to mismatch I don't know.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I made a bug report: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/096320.html